# Performing group by, Order by on a table starting from particular date to recent last date

Tags: sql-server, c#

Am sorry if this question sounds so dumb, please help.

I currently use the below MS SQL query to get the list of volunteers on each date and it works perfectly fine,

```
select Date, count(id) as co from volunter Group BY Date Order by Date
```

and the result set looks like this

```
----------
Date       | co
25/2/2016    8
5/3/2016     18
25/3/2016    28
```

i Now want to perform the same but from a particular date, say from 5/3/2016 to the latest date in the table or say till the last record in the table, how do i do this ? Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause, like: `where Date >= '2016-03-05'` in the statement. Also, always tag a question with the appropriate DBMS tag (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, DB2, etc...)

Comment: Hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ thank you for reply, it gives me syntax error .  "where Date >= 3/19/2016 select Date, count(id) as co from volunter Group BY Date Order by Date"

Comment: You've missed the quotation marks around the date in @ypercubeᵀᴹ's example. And the WHERE clause goes after the FROM clause. Please read the basics first.

Comment: And really use a sane format for dates. You can't have both `'25/2/2016'` and `'3/19/2016'` as dates. In any calendar I know, in Earth, Venus or Mars. Not sure about Neptune, they may have 19 months there.

Comment: @AndriyM amazing, silly me, this worked like charm, thank you so much

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ sorry actually i was using conventional ways here, now am getting the records correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `WHERE` clause in the statement, like: `where Date >= '2016-03-05'`:

```
select v.Date, count(v.id) as co 
from volunter as v
where v.Date >= '2016-03-05'
group by v.Date 
order by v.Date ;
```

- Details may differ depending on the DBMS you use. For SQL Server for example, the safe format for the `date` and `datetime` types is `'YYYYMMDD'`, so it would be better to write the where as `where v.Date >= '20160305'`. In Oracle and Postgres you could use `where v.Date >= DATE '2016-03-05'`.
- `Date` is a reserved keyword in some DBMS, so it would be better to choose another name for that column. Or always prefix it with the table name/alias.